# Shortening the URL with RewriteRule: Remove content root entirely?

Tags: mod-rewrite, websphere-commerce

I an trying to shorten an URL like this:

```
www.mystore.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CategoryDisplay?langId=-1& storeId=10001&catalogId=10001&categoryId=10006
```

...to this:

```
www.mystore.com/CategoryDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10001&catalogId=10001& categoryId=10006
```

Using the examples from IBM I can easily get rid of most of the URL simply by doing this in the Apache configuration:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/(.*) /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/$1
```

And then adding this to the wc-server.xml file:

```
<context-root-rewrite value=“/shop” />
```

Is it possible to get rid of the /shop/ prefix entirely? It seems that nothing in Apache (aka IIS) prevents this, but will Websphere Commerce choke on it?

Comment: What version of WCS are you using?  There are much better/more robust ways to do this depending on the version/fix pack

Comment: Version 7 FP 4. I am going by the slides that were passed out in Madrid 2012 if you know of those: Use mod.rewrite for the static part of the URL then pattern files for translating language, store, catalog and category.

Comment: I don't know of those, but for this particular case, does 
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/$1
<context-root-rewrite value=“/” />

work?

Comment: Sorry, I've been ill for a few days. Will check and report back.

Comment: Hmm, just realized that I can't test that in my dev environment, as I am running inside WCS. Will get back to you once THAT's fixed.

Comment: Will this work on V7 FP4?

Comment: Michael: Unfortunately that does not work. It looks like the graphical assets get the wrong path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Because in this case we are just rerouting the requests for the servlet. If there's any other content there will be confusion. We are basically moving a sub-branch to be a sub-branch of the root, but there are other sub-branches.

Answer (score 1):

Just put

**httpd.conf:**

```
 RewriteRule ^/(?!wcsstore)(.*) /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/$1 [PT,L]
```

**wc-server.xml:**

```
  <SEOConfiguration defaultUrl=""
                    dynamicUrl="true"
                    enable="true">
      <context-root-rewrite value="/" />
  </SEOConfiguration>
```

Restart the server1 and http server.